# Why does Microsoft Code Analysis check for arguments being null only publicly accessible methods?

Tags: c#, null, code-analysis, roslyn

Microsoft Code Analysis’s [CA1062](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182182.aspx) rule checks that reference-type arguments are not passed with `null`.

Why does this check only publicly accessible methods? Should not internal and private methods also be checked? How can one guarantee for internal methods that a null argument will not be passed?

I am asking because I noticed with Reflector/ILSpy that in the [Roslyn September 2012 CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx), the `internal` constructors for the various syntax nodes (see the `SyntaxList` class) do not check for null arguments, whereas the `public` factory methods for the syntax nodes do check for null arguments. In this case, how would Microsoft guarantee that the internal usages of the `SyntaxList` constructor do not pass null?

Comment: If you're looking to do these kind of checks in your own code, [Microsoft Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) supports static and runtime checks for such errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case, how would Microsoft guarantee that the internal usages of the SyntaxList constructor do not pass null?

Presumably because they have tests which mean they're confident in their own code. If you validate all of your input, and you have confidence that your own code is correct, then you can be confident that your calls to your *internal* APIs have valid input.

Of course it's possible that there's a bug in the implementation, and that it would either generate or allow the pass-through of invalid input to some internal method. If you want to put more validation on internal calls, that's fine. But it's at the public API level that validation is most essential.

Comment: If one is unit testing an internal class, would not passing `null` to the constructor be a valid unit test? For example, the `WithManyChildren` class has `WithManyChildren(ArrayElement<SyntaxNode>[] children){ this.children = children;` as part of its constructor, and subsequent usages of `this.children` do not validate that it is not null.

Comment: @cm007: Not if you never expect that to be a problem, because you know that code can only be called via other tested code which is expected to validate everything. Again, *you can decide* to validate more thoroughly and test that... but trusting your own tested code is also a valid philosophy IMO.

Comment: And for the record, some of the "missing null checks" in the Roslyn syntax are there in debug builds as Debug.Assert calls. They are omitted in retail builds (like the CTP) that we ship.